# How are Classes and Function Constructors different from one another

Tags: javascript

From my understanding, a class is a blueprint with the following syntax:

```
class User {

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  sayHi() {
    alert(this.name);
  }

}

let user = new User("John");
user.sayHi(); //John
```

user now has the properties of the class User, but function constructors, also do that:

```
function User(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.isAdmin = false;
}

let user = new User("Jack");

alert(user.name); // Jack
alert(user.isAdmin); // false
```

I understand that classes have things like static, super, extend etc. How are they different?(Other than things like static etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How are Classes and Function Constructors different from one another

They aren't.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

> JavaScript classes, introduced in ECMAScript 2015, are primarily
>   syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based
>   inheritance. The class syntax does not introduce a new object-oriented
>   inheritance model to JavaScript. JavaScript classes provide "syntactic
>   sugar" to create objects and deal with inheritance.